# Kadane's Algorithm for 2D array with known boundaries

Tags: python, algorithm, multidimensional-array, kadanes-algorithm

I have implemented the Kadane's algorithm for a 2D array in Python 2 with known boundaries, but I'm using the implementation for an online contest and the time it takes is more than the time given.

So that made me think if there is maybe another algorithm similar to Kadane's that has a smaller complexity, or if my code can be optimized in a way. My implementation works for any array with dimensions `N` x `M` and a subarray with dimensions `maxRows` x `maxCols`.

***maxSumSubarray.py***

```
import numpy as np

# returns the maximum sum for the given vector using kadane's algorithm, with
# maxRows maximum members in the sum
def kadane1DwithBounds(maxRows):
    global temp
    m = s = sum(temp[i] for i in xrange(maxRows))
    k = 0

    for i in xrange(1, N - maxRows + 1):
        s -= temp[k]
        s += temp[maxRows + i - 1]
        k += 1
        m = max(m, s)

    return m

# prints the maximum "area" given by the values of an NxM array inside a
# subarray with dimensions maxRows x maxCols. temp holds the latest vector to be
# given to kadane1DwithBounds()
def kadane2DwithBounds(maxRows, maxCols):
    global temp
    for i in xrange(N):
        temp[i] = sum(table[i][j] for j in xrange(maxCols))

    m = kadane1DwithBounds(maxRows)

    k = 0
    for j in xrange(1, M - maxCols + 1):
        for i in xrange(N):
            temp[i] -= table[i][k]
            temp[i] += table[i][maxCols + j - 1]
        k += 1
        m = max(m, kadane1DwithBounds(maxRows))

    print m

line = map(int, raw_input().split())
N = line[0]
M = line[1]
maxRows = line[2]
maxCols = line[3]

table = []
temp = np.empty(N, dtype = int)

for _ in xrange(N):
    table.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))

kadane2DwithBounds(maxRows, maxCols)
```

***test.txt***

```
4 8 2 3
1 1 2 3 3 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 1 1 3 3 4
0 0 1 1 3 2 2 1
```

Run with

```
python maxSumSubarray.py < test.txt
```

it gives

```
16
```

which is correct and is the following rectangle:

```
2 2 2
3 3 4
```

I've tried with other dimensions too and I'm pretty sure it works fine. Only problem is time/complexity. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are seeking improvements to working code, then this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I thought to ask here first in case there is a more suitable method. If I don't get any answers I'll consider your advice.